# Shapen raises IllegalStateException when attempting to convert java code

Tags: c#, java, sharpen-tool

I am attempting to port the [lucenetransform](http://code.google.com/p/lucenetransform/) code from java to c# using the Sharpen Tool. I used the sharpen setup information at [PaulDB.getWords()](http://www.pauldb.me/post/14916717048/a-guide-to-sharpen-a-great-tool-for-converting-java)

When I run the conversion process, I get the following error

> !SESSION 2012-12-15 14:55:21.773 -----------------------------------------------
>   eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200 java.version=1.6.0_38 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64,
>   WS=win32, NL=en_IN Framework arguments:  -application
>   sharpen.core.application -header
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\header.txt
>   sharpened/src -cp
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\junit\junit-3.8.2.jar
>   -cp C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\junit_4\junit-4.5.jar
>   -cp C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\copylibs\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
>   -cp C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar
>   @sharpen-all-options Command-line arguments:  -data
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\sharpen -application
>   sharpen.core.application -header
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\header.txt
>   sharpened/src -cp
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\junit\junit-3.8.2.jar
>   -cp C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\junit_4\junit-4.5.jar
>   -cp C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\copylibs\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
>   -cp C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar
>   @sharpen-all-options
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-12-15 14:55:28.110 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException    at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.pushExpression(CSharpBuilder.java:3364)    at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:2171)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.StringLiteral.accept0(StringLiteral.java:136)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AssertStatement.accept0(AssertStatement.java:167)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:136)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)    at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visitBlock(CSharpBuilder.java:1865)    at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.processBlock(CSharpBuilder.java:1826)  at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visitBodyDeclarationBlock(CSharpBuilder.java:1793)
>     at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.mapMethodParts(CSharpBuilder.java:1540)
>     at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.processMethodDeclaration(CSharpBuilder.java:1495)
>     at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:1346)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:489)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)   at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:3384)     at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.mapMembers(CSharpBuilder.java:760)     at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.processTypeDeclaration(CSharpBuilder.java:373)
>     at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder$2.run(CSharpBuilder.java:284)     at
>   sharpen.core.framework.DynamicVariable.using(DynamicVariable.java:46)
>     at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:279)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:467)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:219)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)   at
>   sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.run(CSharpBuilder.java:134)    at
>   sharpen.core.SharpenConversion$2.run(SharpenConversion.java:121)  at
>   sharpen.core.framework.DynamicVariable.using(DynamicVariable.java:46)
>     at sharpen.core.framework.Environments.runWith(Environments.java:23)
>     at sharpen.core.SharpenConversion.convert(SharpenConversion.java:119)
>     at sharpen.core.SharpenConversion.run(SharpenConversion.java:105)   at
>   sharpen.core.SharpenConversionBatch.convertCompilationUnit(SharpenConversionBatch.java:72)
>     at
>   sharpen.core.framework.ConversionBatch.convertPair(ConversionBatch.java:79)
>     at
>   sharpen.core.framework.ConversionBatch.run(ConversionBatch.java:71)
>     at
>   sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.convertTo(SharpenApplication.java:96)
>     at
>   sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.convert(SharpenApplication.java:83)
>     at
>   sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.safeRun(SharpenApplication.java:71)
>     at sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.start(SharpenApplication.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)    at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:34)

The eclipse console shows the following information

> Buildfile:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\run-sharpen.xml clean:
>   sharpen-docs:
>        [copy] Copying 22 files to C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\sharpen\sharpened\src
>        [exec] project: sharpened
>        [exec] Configuration Class: null
>        [exec] classpath entry: C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\junit\junit-3.8.2.jar
>        [exec] classpath entry: C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\junit_4\junit-4.5.jar
>        [exec] classpath entry: C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\copylibs\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
>        [exec] classpath entry: C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\lib\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar
>        [exec] source folder: src
>        [exec] Pascal case mode: NamespaceAndIdentifiers
>        [exec] Native type system mode on.
>        [exec] Organize usings mode on.
>        [exec] Header file: C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\header.txt
>        [exec] AbstractPipedTransformer.java
>        [exec] AbstractTransformedIndexOutput.java
>        [exec] /sharpened/src/org/apache/lucene/store/transform/AbstractTransformedIndexOutput.java(227):
>   Unresolved cref target
>        [exec] ByteIndexInput.java
>        [exec] CompressedIndexDirectory.java
>        [exec] DataDecryptor.java
>        [exec] DataEncryptor.java
>        [exec] DataTransformer.java
>        [exec] DecompressionChunkCache.java
>        [exec] DeflateDataTransformer.java
>        [exec] InflateDataTransformer.java
>        [exec] LRUChunkCache.java
>        [exec] NullTransformer.java
>        [exec] ReadDataTransformer.java
>        [exec] /sharpened/src/org/apache/lucene/store/transform/SequentialTransformedIndexOutput.java(63):
>   Parameter 'pLevel' not found.
>        [exec] /sharpened/src/org/apache/lucene/store/transform/SequentialTransformedIndexOutput.java(64):
>   Parameter 'deflateCount' not found.
>        [exec] ReadPipeTransformer.java
>        [exec] SequentialTransformedIndexOutput.java
>        [exec] SharedBufferCache.java
>        [exec] StoreDataTransformer.java
>        [exec] StorePipeTransformer.java
>        [exec] StreamIndexOutput.java
>        [exec] TransformedDirectory.java
>        [exec] TransformedIndexInput.java
>        [exec] ERROR: null
>        [exec] java.lang.IllegalStateException
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.pushExpression(CSharpBuilder.java:3364)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:2171)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.StringLiteral.accept0(StringLiteral.java:136)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AssertStatement.accept0(AssertStatement.java:167)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:136)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visitBlock(CSharpBuilder.java:1865)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.processBlock(CSharpBuilder.java:1826)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visitBodyDeclarationBlock(CSharpBuilder.java:1793)
>        [exec] Conversion finished in 4468ms.
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.mapMethodParts(CSharpBuilder.java:1540)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.processMethodDeclaration(CSharpBuilder.java:1495)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:1346)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:489)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:3384)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.mapMembers(CSharpBuilder.java:760)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.processTypeDeclaration(CSharpBuilder.java:373)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder$2.run(CSharpBuilder.java:284)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.framework.DynamicVariable.using(DynamicVariable.java:46)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.visit(CSharpBuilder.java:279)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:467)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:219)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.CSharpBuilder.run(CSharpBuilder.java:134)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenConversion$2.run(SharpenConversion.java:121)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.framework.DynamicVariable.using(DynamicVariable.java:46)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.framework.Environments.runWith(Environments.java:23)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenConversion.convert(SharpenConversion.java:119)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenConversion.run(SharpenConversion.java:105)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenConversionBatch.convertCompilationUnit(SharpenConversionBatch.java:72)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.framework.ConversionBatch.convertPair(ConversionBatch.java:79)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.framework.ConversionBatch.run(ConversionBatch.java:71)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.convertTo(SharpenApplication.java:96)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.convert(SharpenApplication.java:83)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.safeRun(SharpenApplication.java:71)
>        [exec]   at sharpen.core.SharpenApplication.start(SharpenApplication.java:50)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>        [exec]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>        [exec]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>        [exec]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>        [exec]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
>        [exec]   at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:34)
>        [exec] An error has occurred. See the log file
>        [exec] C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\sharpen.metadata.log.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\run-sharpen.xml:59:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows\workspace\lucenetransform\run-sharpen.xml:20:
>   exec returned: 13
>
> Total time: 10 seconds

Can't seem to find any help on this issue from Google. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It might be not the correct explanation of what is causing the issue, but when I was converting code with sharpen I had tried to change the source files when such thing happened. 

It is a bit like hacking around the problem, but it worked for me.

Comment: hi, could you please explain what you mean by changing the files ? I have opened the file and added a few line breaks to change the file and then saved it. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: For me removing comments on the methods did the trick. I would start with the cref in the error message and see if that helps:

sharpened/src/org/apache/lucene/store/transform/AbstractTransformedIndexOutput.java(227): Unresolved cref target [exec] ByteIndexInput.java [exec

Comment: I have abandoned trying to use sharpen for now.

Comment: I did the same. It is such a shame, the tool has great promise!